# TimePickerDialog not showing AM/PM button in Gingerbread using SDK v22

Tags: android

I've recently begun updating my app to use appcompat-v22. One thing I've noticed is that on a Gingerbread emulator, the timepicker dialog is missing the AM/PM button.

[image]

I can click the empty space (inside the red circle in the below picture), and it will alternate between AM/PM, but I still can't see the actual button on the dialog.

[image]

Is this a bug in the SDK / compatability libraries, or maybe I did something horribly wrong when creating the dialog?

**Edit:** I didn't originally include my code, as it is very simple, I am not editing dialog themes at all. Note that it works as expected when using SDK v21 as the target.

```
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(adapter.getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }), reminderItem.hour, reminderItem.minute, false);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle(R.string.createReminder);
        timePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: "Is this a bug in the SDK / compatability libraries" Not sure. "maybe I did something horribly wrong when creating the dialog" Let's see the dialog code ;)

Comment: Are you modifying the styles or themes in a way that might affect the dialog? How are you creating and displaying the dialog? Post XML and/or code.

Comment: I've added the code, I'm not doing anything all that special as far as I can tell, no special styles/themes directed at dialogs. My activity themes are inheriting from style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and style/Theme.AppCompat, if that helps

Comment: Note that I omitted some setButton(...) code which was replacing the text with "Accept" and "Delete reminder" in the images above. I commented those out and had the same issue, so I didn't want to pollute the question with that.

Comment: Could it be in 24 hour mode? Easy to test by incrementing the hour picker. I'm not sure if that determines the AM/PM display though.

Comment: It isn't 24 hour mode, the 5th parameter of TimePickerDialog is "is24HourView" which I've set as false. The emulator is also in 12-hour mode. Also as can be seen in the images above, there is a button that is toggling AM/PM in the dialog, it just can't be seen.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that was it but just wanted to throw it out there. Have you tried it on an actual device?

Comment: I wonder if it could be a resource issue with v22? Maybe search the SDK folder for the TimePickerDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Support Library 22.1.0